# Dimensional error when trying to train keras model

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I want to build a 3d dcgan out of a 2d dcgan. While everything worked for 2d, in 3d I got a dimensional error when trying to train the generator. Sadly, the error thrown is pretty cryptic and I can't make much out of it:

> 2019-05-26 17:47:47.992134: F .\tensorflow/core/util/mkl_util.h:607]
>   Check failed: dims == sizes.size() (5 vs. 4)

As of now I checked if each model can run by itself and they do. As expected the generator gives me a cube and the discriminator does it's job too. I tried looking up the mkl_util header.

This is my init:

```
    def __init__(self):
        # Input shape
        self.axis = 16
        self.channels = 1
        self.img_shape = (self.axis, self.axis, self.axis, self.channels)
        self.dimensions = 500

        optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.0002, 0.5)

        self.discriminator = self.build_discriminator()
        self.discriminator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

        self.generator = self.build_generator()

        z = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(self.dimensions,))
        img = self.generator(z)
        self.discriminator.trainable = False
        valid = self.discriminator(img)
        self.combined = tf.keras.models.Model(z, valid)
        self.combined.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)
```

And, here the error occurred `self.combined.train_on_batch(noise, valid)`

```
        valid = np.ones((batch_size, 1))
        noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (batch_size, self.dimensions))
        g_loss = self.combined.train_on_batch(noise, valid)
```

I wouldn't expect that result at all as the generating model runs by itself and so does the discriminator.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I am trying to train a 3D unet.